# Вопрос об отношении к определённой части речи сочетания "в самом деле"

Tags: морфология

***В самом деле*** является наречием или каждое слово рассматривается здесь отдельно при определении частей речи?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**В самом деле** – это наречное  выражение, оно только **используется в значении наречия** (как указано в словаре), но грамматически является словосочетанием из трех слов.

В – предлог,  САМОМ – местоименное прилагательное (с усилительным оттенком, высоким проявлением свойства), ДЕЛЕ – существительное.

**В самом деле.** I. **в зн. нареч.** В действительности; действительно, точно. Он в самом деле настоящий учёный. Считают меня хуже, чем я в самом деле. II. **в зн. вводн. словосоч.** Действительно, правда; в конце концов. Да не плачь ты, в самом деле.